# Is it possible to point to templated class without knowing the template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to do something like this, but I'm not sure if it is possible. I can't find any information on Google.

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
  T *ptr;
};

class Other {
private:
  Container *container_ref;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is run-time polymorphism, not templates which are sometimes called compile-time polymorphism.

Comment: Sure!  Make `Other` a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not, but if you are in charge of `Container` then you can make it inherit from a non-templated base class and keep a pointer to that.

Comment: And that's in fact what the implementation of `shared_ptr` does to keep track of the type of the thing you allocate so that it can later do non-polymorphic deletion.

Answer (score 2):

No. A template isn't a class, it's the instructions for how to build a class. Without the template parameters (either explicit or implied) it isn't complete.

You could look into [Boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html) for a solution to your problem.

Comment: There's a reason people insist on calling it a class *template* rather than a template *class* :) It really is a template and not a class!